# Why do the images not change to previous ones on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The mouse hover is showing the `<div>`s normally but after the first time I move the mouse it no longer shows the other `<div>`s. It eventually stays on the last image and doesn’t change to another.

I tried with `fadeToggle` but I would like it to be fixed to the last image that appeared, but `fadeToggle` hides the last image when you mouse out.

```js
$('.second').hover(function() {
  $('.showsecond').fadeIn();
});
$('.third').hover(function() {
  $('.showthird').fadeIn();
});
$('.fourth').hover(function() {
  $('.showfourth').fadeIn();
});
$('.fifth').hover(function() {
  $('.showfifth').fadeIn();
});
```

```css
.menuimage {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.menuimagefirst {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-6">
  <ul>
    <li class="first"><a href="#">first</a></li>
    <li class="second"><a href="#">second</a></li>
    <li class="third"><a href="#">third</a></li>
    <li class="fourth"><a href="#">fourth</a></li>
    <li class="fifth"><a href="#">fifth</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
  <div class="menuimage menuimagefirst showfirst">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/o87PUwV.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="menuimage showsecond">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ICs7TVH.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="menuimage showthird">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/n9gdy8N.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="menuimage showfourth">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/o87PUwV.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="menuimage showfifth">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ICs7TVH.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/castordida/fwou1hvg/17/

I expected it to always show the last image and keep that image until I hover on another link.

**UPDATE 29/08/19:**

Sorry i did not mention that what i am using is in the wordpress menu, so i made use of classes and not data-toggle unfortunately. I tried to add data-toggle unsuccessfully to wordpress menu.

Comment: because they are on top of each other, the one on top will be always on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit a dirty work, but should work ;)

P.S : You can ignore .menu-item css as its just for aesthetics. Though rest of the css are important.

```js
$('.menu-item').mouseenter(function() 
{
   var $this = $(this);
   var hover_elem_classes = $this.attr("class");
   var class_list;
   class_list = hover_elem_classes.split(" ");

   var currentImageClass="";
   for(var i in class_list)
   {
      var styleClass = class_list[i];
      if(styleClass.startsWith("show"))
      {
          currentImageClass = styleClass;
          break;
      }
   }
   
   
   var $activeImg = $(".menuimage."+currentImageClass);
   if(!$activeImg.hasClass("active"))
   {
      $(".menuimage.active").stop().fadeOut().removeClass("active");
      $activeImg.addClass("active").fadeIn();  
   }
});
```

```css
.menuimage{display:none;position:absolute;}
.menu-item{padding:5px 10px;list-style-type:none;display:inline;text-transform:uppercase;}
.menuimage.active{z-index:10;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-6">
  <ul>
    <li class="menu-item showfirst adasd adasd"><a href="root/first">first</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item showsecond zxczxc xczxczc"><a href="root/second">second</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item showthird fghfgh ghfgh"><a href="root/third">third</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item showfourth adasdg gfhfgh"><a href="root/fourth">fourth</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item showfifth zxczxc czxc"><a href="root/fifth">fifth</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
  <div class="menuimage active showfirst" style="display:block;">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/o87PUwV.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="menuimage showsecond">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ICs7TVH.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="menuimage showthird">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/n9gdy8N.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="menuimage showfourth">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/o87PUwV.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="menuimage showfifth">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ICs7TVH.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not working because wordpress <li> has another classes like that: <li id="menu-item-38492" class="proteinbarhv menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-38492">

Comment: Changed some code and used anchor to get the class from href. If that too isn't helping, share the actual code. Will find a way to get around ;)

Comment: Also a better option than href would be adding a custom first class to <a> tag. Let me know if you can do that. Will update the code accordingly V

Comment: This menu is used with links too, look this image just to you understand the logic and structure: https://imgur.com/U3Sshxm

Comment: Issue is there is no mapping between the <li> and <img> tags. There has to be something that sould link both. Are you able to add custom class to .menuimage element?

Comment: Yeap, .menuimage i can change everything. What i cant change is .menu-item.

Comment: Check the changes. This should work. Add a custom class starting with show and the exact same class in .menuimage element :) As per your screenshoot, in `menu-item` add class `showpastadeamendoimhv` Hope that helps !!

Comment: Works like a charm, ty for the patience

Comment: I can sometimes be a charmer :ppp !!

Comment: Im getting some syntax error : Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .menuimage.

Comment: Send in the print screen? or copy paste exact text. Possibility you haven't added class to one of the menus. The class should start with `show` like `showpastadeamendoimhv`. showfirst class `<li class="menu-item showfirst adasd adasd">` in my case. If you have the site deployed, share link.

Comment: i found, it was in the <li> that had no class, ty

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you do not hide elements after they are shown so when you have an element on top of another element it will not be visible. So you need to hide them.

```js
$("li[data-toggles]").on("mouseenter", function () {
  $(".menuimage.active").stop().hide();
  $($(this).data('toggles')).stop().fadeIn().addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.menuimage {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.menuimagefirst {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-6">
  <ul>
    <li class="first" data-toggles=".showfirst"><a href="#">first</a></li>
    <li class="second" data-toggles=".showsecond"><a href="#">second</a></li>
    <li class="third" data-toggles=".showthird"><a href="#">third</a></li>
    <li class="fourth" data-toggles=".showfourth"><a href="#">fourth</a></li>
    <li class="fifth" data-toggles=".showfifth"><a href="#">fifth</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
  <div class="menuimage menuimagefirst showfirst">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/o87PUwV.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="menuimage showsecond">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ICs7TVH.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="menuimage showthird">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/n9gdy8N.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="menuimage showfourth">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/o87PUwV.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="menuimage showfifth">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ICs7TVH.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't mention it before, this is for a wordpress menu so when you hover over the links in the menu the image changes. But I can't put a different data-toggle for each menu <li>. I can just put the classes.

Comment: Can i do that just with classes ? Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

You've got a lot of unnecessary code here and it's contributing to your issues.

There is no need to create an `img` element for each picture you wish to show. Since you only want to show one image at a time, one `img` element is all you need. You'll just programatically change its source as needed. The image paths themselves will be kept in an array and a counter will be used to keep track of which index from the array to use as the source for the image element.

By eliminating the multiple `img` elements, you can eliminate the CSS that positions them, which is the source of the issue you are currently facing (layering of images).

Also, don't use `a` elements unless you are navigating somewhere when they are clicked as `a` elements are exclusively for navigation. Instead, you can set up your event on the `li` element that the user will be mousing over.

```js
let imgs = [
  "https://i.imgur.com/o87PUwV.jpg",
  "https://i.imgur.com/ICs7TVH.jpg",
  "https://i.imgur.com/n9gdy8N.jpg",
  "https://i.imgur.com/o87PUwV.jpg",
  "https://i.imgur.com/ICs7TVH.jpg"
];

let idx = 0;

$('.imgNav').on("mouseover", function() {

  $(".menuimage").fadeOut(function(){
    // As long as the index is less than the highest one in the array...
    if(idx < (imgs.length - 1)){
      // Set the source of the image element to the next path in the array
      $(".menuimage")[0].src = imgs[++idx];
    } else {
      // Otherwise, reset the index
      idx = 0;
    }
    // Show the image element now that its source has been changed.
    $(".menuimage").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-6">
  <ul>
    <li class="imgNav">first</li>
    <li class="imgNav">second</li>
    <li class="imgNav">third</li>
    <li class="imgNav">fourth</li>
    <li class="imgNav">fifth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
  <img class="menuimage" src="https://i.imgur.com/o87PUwV.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: That's a wordpress menu, because that the links. Sorry i didn't mention before.

Comment: I tried that, but the hover is not showing the right images,every hour he shows a different picture.